# Подскажите примеры работы для pyhon + celery для уменьшения очереди insert в БД

Tags: python, celery

Есть небольшое приложение на python, к нему прилетают данные с разной периодичностью. И сейчас эти данные сразу пишутся в БД mysql (insert делается по каждой порции). В какой-то момент, если слишком много данных, то вылетает ошибка, что с mysql слишком много подключений.
Собственно хочется запихнуть эти порции в очередь celery и уже оттуда одним запросом insert 100-1000 записей делать.
Хоть убейте не могу понять как правильно это сделать, т.к. уровень знания python - noob (((

Comment: `Celery` — это асинхронная очередь задач. Не понимаю, каким образом он поможет Вам.

Comment: Ок, тогда может что-то еще. По-сути нужна просто очередь, чтобы из нее получать пачками данные (т.е. разом берем 100 или 1000 записей) и их писать одним запросом в БД. А не делать отдельный запрос на каждый входящий запрос (сейчас сделано так)

Comment: сейчас приложение написано так: запускается, создает потоки в каждом потоке при получении данных создается подключение к БД и делается insert и закрывается подключение к БД

Comment: вот собственно хочу уйти от кучи открытых соединений и в БД писать бОльшими пачками

Comment: даже скорее всего в отдельном процессе чтобы работал именно insert в БД, без основной программы